# How to pull values out of multi-dimensional array?

Tags: java, arrays, loops

Using multi-dimensional arrays is a first for me, so my understanding of some of the aspects that come with these arrays are a bit...vague. Now for a quick review of what this program will be used for once completed...

It would allow a teacher in input a student's name and four corresponding test scores. They can list up to 15 students.

Ex. John Smith: 67 75 84 52 
    Jane Doe: 54 86 81 79

After filling in firstNameField, lastNameField and test1Field-test4Field, you press the addButton which outputs it in another field and outputs every student you add creating a list.

My problem is finding the class average. I would like to find away to pull the four test scores of each student only (and not pull out names) where I would create an equation to find the average, which is easy enough. The thing is, I'm unsure who to pull out all the test scores from the array so I can do that...

```
public class StudentGradesView extends FrameView {

    int [][] aryStudent = new int [15][4]; // [15] being # of students, [4] for test scores
    String[] studentNames = new String[15]; //this isn't being used now...
    int numOfStudents = 0; //listing the students starts off from 0...

    int marks = 0; //might be needed for grabbing out test scores for finding average?

    int test1;
    int test2;
    int test3;
    int test4;

    public StudentGradesView(SingleFrameApplication app) {

//unimportant...for GUI...

}
    private void addButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

        aryStudent[numOfStudents][0] = Integer.parseInt(test1Field.getText());
        aryStudent[numOfStudents][1] = Integer.parseInt(test2Field.getText());
        aryStudent[numOfStudents][2] = Integer.parseInt(test3Field.getText());
        aryStudent[numOfStudents][3] = Integer.parseInt(test4Field.getText());

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();


//The following is the code that list the students and their grades...this code should be fine..

        for (int x=0; x <= numOfStudents && x<15; x++) {
            sb.append(firstNameField.getText() + " " + lastNameField.getText());
            for (int y=0; y < 4; y++) {
                sb.append(" " +aryStudent[x][y]);
           // studentListField.setText("" + firstNameField.getText() + " " + lastNameField.getText() + " " + aryStudent[numOfStudents][y] + "\n" + currentList);
            }
            sb.append("\n");
        }
        studentListField.setText(sb.toString());
        numOfStudents ++;
    }                                         

    private void classAverageButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
```

"int schoolAverage = (test1 + test2 + test3 + test4)/4;" //This is what I hoped would work...but the output is always zero after. So I guess I'm not pulling the test scores out of the array correctly. So I tried a loop similar to what I did above...as of now I'm lost in the dark.

```
        for (int x=0; x <= numOfStudents && x<15; x++) {

            for (int y=0; y < marks && y <4; y++) {
                 averageField.setText("" + /** I'm unsure what to do here */ );
            }
        }

        numOfStudents ++;
        marks++;

       // studentListField.getText(averageField.setText(""));

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is almost right -- you only need one for loop, though. Something along the lines of:

```
for(int x = 0; x < numOfStudents && x<15; x++) {
  averageField.setText((aryStudent[x][0] + aryStudent[x][1] + aryStudent[x][2] + [aryStudent[x][3])/4);
}
```

This will call averageField.setText() *numOfStudents* times. In aryStudent[*x*][*y*], you differentiate between students using *x*, and grades using *y*.

Since the number of grades is fixed (four per student), you can reference each grade directly (aryStudent[*x*][0] for the *xths* student's first grade, aryStudent[*x*][1] for the second, and so on...)

Also, remember that arrays are zero-indexed (a five-element array, will be 0,1,2,3,4 not 1,2,3,4,5) so if you're starting at x=0 and testing for x <= numOfStudents, your loop will iterate numOfStudents+1 times, possibly causing an ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException.